# Как перебирать каждое значение?

Tags: python

Мне нужно, чтобы в коде определённая переменная менялась в зависимости от значения другой. Например, первая переменная оканчивается на 0, тогда вторая переменная должна принять одно значение. Если переменная оканчивается на цифры от 1 до 4, то у второй переменной другое значение. Если переменная оканчивается на цифры от 5 до 9, то третье значение.

Есть ли вариант, чтобы написать таким образом:

```
if x == 0:
    y = '1 meaning'
elif x == (тут будут перебираться значения от 1 до 4):
    y = '2 meaning'
else:
    y = '3'
```

Я мог бы перечислить каждое значение от 1 до 4 через `and`, но это будет долго.

Есть ли способ одной записью перечислить все значения в третьей строке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Несколько вариантов:

1. Через `in`, и справа в кортеже перечислить значения:

```
if x in (1, 2, 3, 4):
    ...
```

2. То же самое через `range`:

```
x in range(1, 5)
```

3. Просто через арифметическое сравнение "больше или равно":

```
1 <= x <= 4
```

Через `and` и не получится, потому что `and` предполагает, что каждое условие выполняется, а переменная не может быть равна одновременно нескольким числам, т.е. условие типа `a == b and a == c`, где `b != c` - всегда ложное. Должно быть `or`, а не `and`.

Comment: Да, я перепутал, вместо OR, написал and.
Спасибо